# GestureListener select bad item when scroll moves

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit

I saw here and in some articles that I should use GestureListener to get Tap from user then use SelectionChanged. I tried it and I like it. But I have problem with it. When my listbox moves (scrolls) and I try tap I get bad item (I get item from last tap). When I scroll and wait for stopping scroll and then tap everything is fine (I get exactly item which I tap on). Anyone else with this problem? Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As (according to your tags) you're targetting 7.1, there is no need to have to use a `GestureListener` to detect `Tap` events.

All UIElements in Silverlight 4 (which 7.1 is based on) support a built in `Tap` event. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap(v=vs.95).aspx

Using a `GestureListener` has an unnecessary performance overhead and can cause other issues as you're discovering.

You should use a `Tap` event in the individual `ListBoxItem`s or the `SelectionChanged` event on the `ListBox` not both.
If you create a new Databound Application, the code in the default project files will show an example of how to use `SelectionChanged` and in that instance trigger a page navigation.

In future, you may also get a better, faster answer by showing the code you are having problems with, not just describing it.

Comment: Oh, I found in your blog this article: http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2012/02/dont-use-onselectionchanged-event-to.html and that´s why I used gesturelistener in first place. But you´re right and listboxitem has tap event. So this is solved.

Comment: Clarifying comment add to that post. Sorry if I led you down the wrong path.